# Get a visitors AD user name in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have a basic web form for our company's intranet and all users are logged in to the domain via AD authentication, can I extract a visitors user name in c#?

Comment: +1 for getting him to accept all his other answers...I hope he accepted the appropriate answers.

Comment: @yoda - new user, might want to cut him a little slack and explain how to use the site instead.  @TheDudeAbides -- one of the tenets of the site is to, if possible, mark the answer that best answers your question as the accepted answer.  Do this by clicking the check mark next to the best answer.

Comment: Well, I went back and picked the one's that got me on the right track. Some of my questions were unfairly vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `User` property on the current Page, like so,

```
var username = this.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to use a particular namespace?

Comment: @TheDudeAbides - If the code is in the context of a `System.Web.UI.Page`, then no.  You already have the property on the current Page.  If you are trying to get it elsewhere, then you'll need to reference the current HttpContext and get the User property from that.  Try to avoid referencing the static HttpContext.Current, if you can though.  It will make your code harder to test. Without code, I can't really advise you any better than that.

Comment: "Try to avoid referencing the static HttpContext.Current, if you can though. It will make your code harder to test" - don't really understand this comment.  If you need a property of HttpContext.Current, then you'll have to access it somehow, and I don't see why doing so via a property of the Page class would be any more testable than accessing the static property.

Comment: @Joe -- rather than reference the static verison, you could use injection to another class that you use from your page.  That is, you pass in a reference to an HttpContext object in the class constructor rather than refer to it as a static dependency.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows Authentication, and don't allow anonymous access, then `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` will have the name of the currently logged on user in the format `domain\username`.

If you want more info from AD (e.g. a display name), then you need to use the classes in the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace.  You may need to provide credentials to access AD if your site is running under a restricted account such as the Network Service account.